# How to place the toolbar to the top in fluxbox?

Tags: fluxbox

The default location of toolbar is in the bottom of the screen. Is it possible to place it to the top instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the values of `session.screen0.slit.placement` and/or `session.screen0.toolbar.placement` to `TopCenter` in your [`~/.fluxbox/init` file](http://fluxbox-wiki.org/category/howtos/en/Editing_the_init_file.html) and reload the configuration:

```
session.screen0.toolbar.placement: TopCenter
```

The available placements are `BottomCenter`, `BottomLeft`, `BottomRight`, `LeftCenter`, `RightCenter`, `TopCenter`, `TopLeft`, and `TopRight`.

See also [`man fluxbox` ("Resources")](http://fluxbox.org/help/man-fluxbox.php#_resources) for all of the available configuration options.

Comment: or .. click on the toolbar with right-mouse and then select the placement from the menu.

Comment: @akira - in fact no, the right-click is not available on all systems: it is absent in Manjaro Fluxbox for example

Comment: add `OnDesktop Mouse3 :RootMenu` to your .fluxbox/keys